# Check if current Emacs buffer contains a string

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, buffer

I have a buffer open in emacs. I want a function that will return `t` if the current buffer contains the string, otherwise it returns `nil`.

```
(defun buffer-contains-substring (string)
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is careful to not change where you are, or damage any match data.

```
(defun buffer-contains-substring (string)
  (save-excursion
    (save-match-data
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (search-forward string nil t))))
```